# How to create a page to edit a database

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications

I'm trying to build a website that provides a login for users. Once these users login, they will be able to perform functions that will likely query a database. At some point I will need to add/modify/delete contents in the database and I'm wondering how I would be able create a page on the website that I'd only have access to. Ideally I wouldn't like to have a page on my website that allows me to edit information in my database because it could be susceptible to attacks. So how would the experts from stackoverflow create a page to edit information in their database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get db management software like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)
 with login abilities (or utilize the authentication by HTTP server)

Answer (score 0):

Well, create a normal page - but put access restrictions on so that you're only allowed to use it if the logged in account is an administrator. (You define the administrator roles, and make sure you are one.)

You might also want to make sure the page is only served to some known IP addresses - although that becomes a pain when you suddenly want to use it from elsewhere...